Adding email link to site to avoid "Choose application" message
How can I add an (obfuscated) email link to my website that opens the viewer'e email app instead of bring up the "Choose an application" message? I just have the "mailto:xxxx@xxxxx.com" link tag.

That's a function of the user's Operating System. If you/they had associated "mailto" links already to an app, they wouldn't have to choose the app each time.
